# what is a "pending state" in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

from react documentation:

in the bollow code , a => a + 1 is an updater function. It takes the **pending state** and calculates the next state from it.

React puts your updater functions in a queue. Then, during the next render, it will call them in the same order:

a => a + 1 will receive 42 as the pending state and return 43 as the next state.

a => a + 1 will receive 43 as the pending state and return 44 as the next state.

a => a + 1 will receive 44 as the pending state and return 45 as the next state.

There are no other queued updates, so React will store 45 as the current state in the end.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(42);

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(a => a + 1);
    setCount(a => a + 1);
    setCount(a => a + 1);
  }
  alert(count)
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      You pressed me {count} times
    </button>
  );
}
```

what is the pending state ? is it the same as the current state?

Comment: Pending state is the state before it is going to be used to update/rerender the component. Current state should be regarded as immutable.

Comment: but  the first setstate function takes 42 as pending state which is the same as current state

Comment: Pending state is the "buffered" or "queued" state to be used next render. You have updated the pending state in the first call, so in the next `setCount`, `a` is the updated pending state, which is `43`.